# For loop only showing one data

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, cordova, for-loop

so I'm trying to fetch data from my existing database but in my for loop it just showing one data but it should be two data that is showing.

Here's my code:

```
 copyDatabaseFile('sample.db').then(function () {
      // success! :)
      var db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('sample.db');
      db.transaction(function (txn) {
        txn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM fish', [], function (tx, res) {
          console.log('Successfully read from pre-populated DB:');
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res.rows.item(0)));

          var length = res.rows.length;
          var s;
          for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
            var fish = res.rows.item(i);
            console.log(fish.name);
        }
        });
      });
    }).catch(function (err) {
      // error! :(
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Here's the output:
[image]

Here's my database:
[image]

Comment: Your for loop looks correct. What does `console.log(res.rows.length)` return?

Comment: Code seems to be ok but just a guess in the dark ```res.rows.length``` might not return the correct count of rows (2). Alternatively you might have a different db which only has one record. You can verify by checking with ```console.log(JSON.stringify(res.rows.item(1)));```